# Rewriting curl http request using Groovy

Tags: http, groovy

Here is my test HTTP request I need to rewrite to use in groovy:

```
curl 'https://api-dev.test.ru/uaa/oauth/token' -H 'Authorization: Basic 1234567=' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form- urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' --data 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'username=theLogin' --data-urlencode 'password=thePassword'
```

Here is the way I've rewritten it:

```
def httpRequest = [path          : 'https://api-dev.test.ru/uaa/oauth/token',
                   headers       : ['Authorization: Basic 1234567='
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'Accept'      : 'application/json, text/plain, */*'],
                   data          : ['grant_type=password'],
                   data_urlencode: ['username=theLogin',
                                    'password=thePassword']
]
```

It seems to be not correctly, because the test app doesn't work with the request. Have I rewritten the request correctly. If I haven't, where is my mistake?

Comment: Above code is a map literal with some lists in it. Could you please show the code, that attempt the actual request and also please add what "does not work" mean?  E.g. stacktraces, errors, logs, ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Http Builder](https://github.com/http-builder-ng/http-builder-ng). Your code would look like:

```
def result = HttpBuilder,configure {
    request.uri = 'https://api-dev.test.ru/uaa/oauth/token'
    request.contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    request.headers.Accept = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
}.post {
    request.auth.basic 'admin', 'myp@$$w0rd'
    request.uri.query = [ grant_type:'password' ]
    request.body = [username:'theLogin', password:'thePassword']
}
```